# python apply lambda from less rows to more rows in different dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames. A has 3360 rows, B has 480 rows. I want to apply some columns from B to A. But it only fits with 480 rows, the rest 2880 rows remain NAs. I am trying to do 'for' loop, but it is not working.Can anyone tell me how can I improve my code?

```
df_item['teamID'] = df_new.apply(lambda x: '%s' (% x['teamID']), axis = 1)
```

[data frame A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ujdt.jpg)
[data frame B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mnaO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply list B:

```
import math

a = [1]*3360
b = [2]*480
a_len = len(a)
b_len = len(b)
c = (b * math.ceil(a_len/b_len))[:a_len]

print(len(c) == len(a))
```